# Get _m_s time format from milliseconds value

Tags: javascript, datetime, formatting

I could have any value in milliseconds like:

> 1040370

I must alert a specific converted time format : `_m_s` (ie:`17m20s`)

Here is how I do it:

```js
function ms(a){
var m = a/1000/60,
s = Math.floor(('0.'+(''+m).split('.')[1])*60);
m = (''+m).split('.')[0];
alert(m+'m'+s+'s');
}

ms(1040370);
```

What do you think?
Is it satisfactory or is there a better way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems overly complicated.  Let the builtin math and parsing functions do the work for you.  And name time values something like `t`.

```js
const ms = t => alert( `${parseInt( t/1000 / 60 )}m${parseInt( t/1000 % 60 )}s` )
ms(1040370);
```